# MC's fighting demons in another dimension, fated to have a child hero

Tags: story-identification, manga

As far as I can remember, the story is about two kids (a male and a female) from different demon slayer clans (they hate each other but fall in love later) in another dimension or something along the way, they are fated to have a child that will emerge as the most powerful warrior and defeat the demons but they vow to make it instead of their child because they don't want their kid to suffer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall and character or place names, or any notable details of the artwork or character portrayals?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour hair did the male and female lead have?

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember if it fit's 100% to your description, but, it could be "Wicked City".

> Japanese horror master Kikuchi (Vampire Hunter D) creates a dark, visceral horror fantasy of a demon-infested Tokyo, where a covert force of powerful humans struggle to prevent worldwide chaos. Renzaburo Taki, a member of the titular Guard who can restructure matter at the molecular level, is partnered with Makie, a beautiful demon who betrays her kind and fights for humanity in the ongoing secret war. - [Urban Fandom - Wicked City Series](https://urbanfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Wicked_City_series)

The third book in the series is focused on the upcoming child to be born and how the child will herald in a new era of peace between the two worlds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as a synopsis or quotes, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).